# Filling a table with non-negative integers given constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have a blank grid of $l$ lines by $c$ columns. Each line and each columns has an (not necessarily unique) associated natural number ($L_i$ for the $i$-th line, and $C_i$ for the $i$-th column). The grid is considered correctly filled if I put non-negative integers in the blanks in such a way that the values in every line and column add up to its respective associated number. Here's an correctly filled grid for $L_1 = 4$, $L_2 = 3$, $C_1 = 3$, $C_2 = 2$, $C_3 = 2$:

```
-------------
| 3 | 1 | 0 |  4
-------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 |  3
-------------
  3   2   2
```

My question is: given arbitrary values for all $L_i$ and $C_i$, how many different correct ways to fill the grid are there?

Comment: Is total sum of the associated numbers of the line and the associated numbers of columns has to be equal?

Comment: Well, I didn't specify, but yes, that's what I was thinking of: in case they aren't, the solution is 0 correct ways to fill